# How to create unit test for Silverlight socket server?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0

How to create a unit test for a Silverlight socket server?

I am using the Silverlight UnitTest framework.

Edit:
I have a simple socket server, which listens for messages. When a message is receive, the server responds to the client. The client is in Silverlight.

How can I create a unit test to check if the server response is correct?

Comment: A unit test normally addresses a single method or function within an app, your question seems to be more along the lines of "How do I test a Silverlight socket server?" which would probably involve generating a stub application that would allow you to fire requests at the server. I wouldn't expect this to be a part of your build or unit-testing activities.

Comment: @Lazarus:  Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I started it as a question back to the OP and then changed my mind mid-flow... doh! Posted as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unit test normally addresses a single method or function within an app, your question seems to be more along the lines of "How do I test a Silverlight socket server?" which would probably involve generating a stub application that would allow you to fire requests at the server. I wouldn't expect this to be a part of your build or unit-testing activities.